# Recommended foods for before surgery?

Tags: surgery, food-safety, pre-suregery-pre-op, electrolytes

For an appendisectomy, what foods would be best to eat pre-op? What foods should be avoided or could make the surgery more difficult? Although there is no appetite and the only thing eaten in the past two days is watermelon which was promptly vomited. There is also a constant intake of fluids with electrolyte tablets. Please, what foods would be recommended and which ones deterred?

Comment: Hopefully a Dr is going to perform the operation.  I would ask them.

Comment: @Paparazzi Yeah, it will be a doctor - assuming this is in the US.

Comment: Appendisectomy (aka appendectomy) is a fairly short, simple procedure so it's not going to make much difference. And since you're unable to hold down solid foods now, the answer is probably "none." I don't know why they're waiting to do the procedure, but a few days without food won't hurt you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the best thing to eat before surgery is [absolutely nothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_by_mouth).  This is done to reduce the risk of [aspiration pneumonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspiration_pneumonia), as your swallowing reflex doesn't work right under general anesthesia.

Your doctor may have specific instructions to the contrary, so ask them.